# GDB is no longer hitting breakpoints in VS Code within docker container

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, cmake, gdb

Once I had set `launch.json` and I ran `gdb` and debugged in my code successfully until something happened and all breakpoint became "gray" with the such message:

*"Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained."*

However, debugger attaches to running program and I even can make steps from `main`, but still breakpoint are not hit... This is C++ project that is built with `cmake` with `gcc` with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG` flag.

`launch.json` is this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./MyProject/project",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/home/AA/workspace",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "/*Cannot write here, but it's fine*/",
            "sourceFileMap": {/*Cannot write here, but it*/}
        },
    ]
}
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an answer in other resources and the most solutions say that you should `-g` option if you compiler a project with `gcc`. It wasn't my case because I use `cmake` but I had one detail that **I debugged code that was run in docker**.

When you work with files in VS code from your user and docker runs project from another user, you should add the option `"sourceFileMap": {}` in `launch.json`:

```
"sourceFileMap": {
                "/home/user/project/file.hpp" : "/home/YourNameBeyondDocker/project/file.hpp",
    ...
```

I added wrong path in this option. When I took it out, my debugger finally started hitting breakpoints!